# Why does my form not get submitted when I press the submit button?

Tags: php, html

so my problem is simply that this form doesn't get submitted. When I press the submit button or the reset button nothing happens. Any ideas?
(I'm using xampp if that has anything to do with it, I'm also a beginner so I don't really have any idea what I'm doing )

This is the signUp.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf8">
    <title>Sign Up Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../allStyles/formstyles.css?php echo time(); ?>"></head>
<body>
    <table  style="width: 30%;" align=center>
        <form action="/loginSystem/signUpHandler.php" method="post"></form>
            <tr style="background-color: #de8704">
                <td  colspan="2" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;"><p style="text-align: left"> Sign Up Form</p></tb>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right"><label for="fname">Name
                <td style="text-align:left"><input type="text" id="fname" value="" placeholder="Enter name"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right"><label for="lname">Last Name
                <td style="text-align:left"><input type="text" id="lname" value="" placeholder="Enter last name"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right">
                <td  style="text-align:left"><input type="radio" name="gender1" id="gender1">Mr
                &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="gender2" id="gender2">Mrs
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right">E-mail
                <td  style="text-align:left"><input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right">Phone Number<td  style="text-align:left"><input type="number" id="pnumber" name="pnumber" placeholder="Enter Phone Number"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right"><label for="username">Username
                <td style="text-align:left"><input type="text" id="username" name="username" value=""></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right">Password<td  style="text-align:left"><input type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="8"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:right;">Confirm <br> Password<td style="text-align:left"><input type="password" id="confpass" name="confpass" maxlength="8"></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td><td><input type="checkbox" value="agree" name="" id="agreed"><label for="agreed">Agree?</label></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: #de8704">
                <td style="text-align: right; background-color: #de8704; padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px;">
                <input class="send_button" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="submitBtn">
                &nbsp;
                <button class="reset_button" type="reset" id="reset" name="resetBtn">Reset</button></td>
            </tr>   
        </form>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The signUpHandler.php is :

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST["submitBtn"]))
{
    header("location: ./signUp.php");
}
else
{
    echo "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<form action="/loginSystem/signUpHandler.php" method="post"></form>`

You closed your form tag before expected, please put your button inside of your form tags maybe it will work :D

Comment: It worked....well this is embarrassing..

Comment: No it's not at all, everyone does same small snags everytime, keep up ! :)